# Решить проблему со скобками в template?

Tags: vue.js

Создаю отдельный компонент. 
Проблема с тегом div там где скобки что не нравится компоненту, а именно template
Тоесть проблема именно в template:

```js
Vue.component('data-tag', {
  data() {
   return {
    dataend: '',
    days: ''
   }
  },
  template: `
  <div>
   <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
   <div> {{days}} days</div>
   <div :class="`tab ${сolorTag}`"></div>
  </div>
  `,
  watch: {
   dataend(){
    this.deadline();
   }
  },
  methods: {
   deadline() {
    const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
    const abs = Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now();
    this.days = Math.ceil(abs/msPerDay);
   }
  },
  computed: {
   сolorTag() {
          switch(true) {
              case this.days > 60: {
                return 'blue'
              }
              case this.days < 60 && this.days>14: {
                return 'yellow'
              }
              case this.days < 14: {
                return 'red'
              }
          }
   }
  }
 });
 new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag"  
 })
```

```css
.tab {
width: 140px;
height: 80px;
background-color: #eee;
}
.red {background-color: red;}
.yellow {background-color: yellow;}
.blue {background-color: blue;}
```

```html
<div id="data-tag">
<data-tag></data-tag>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно документации Vue:

> `template` используют [шаблонные строки JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), чтобы сделать многострочные шаблоны более читаемыми.

Таким образом, руководствуясь [Шаблонными строками](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings), вы вполне можете привести ваш код к виду:

```
    template: `
      <div>
        <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
        <div> {{days}} days</div>
        <div class="tab" :class="сolorTag"></div>
      </div>
    `,
```

```js
Vue.component('data-tag', {
  data() {
    return {
      dataend: '',
      days: ''
    }
  },
  template: `
      <div>
        <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">
        <div> {{days}} days</div>
        <div class="tab" :class="сolorTag"></div>
      </div>
    `,
  watch: {
    dataend() {
      this.deadline();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deadline() {
      const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
      const abs = Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now();
      this.days = Math.ceil(abs / msPerDay);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    сolorTag() {
      switch (true) {
        case this.days > 60:
          {
            return 'blue'
          }
        case this.days < 60 && this.days > 14:
          {
            return 'yellow'
          }
        case this.days < 14:
          {
            return 'red'
          }
      }
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag"
})
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="data-tag">
  <data-tag></data-tag>
</div>
```

Учтите, также

> Эта возможность не поддерживается Internet Explorer (IE), поэтому если вам нужна поддержка IE и нет возможности использовать транспиляцию (например с помощью Babel или TypeScript), то используйте запись с обратными слэшами для многострочных шаблонов вместо них.

```
  template: '\
    <div>\
      <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">\
      <div> {{days}} days</div>\
      <div class="tab" :class="`tab ${сolorTag}`"></div>\
    </div>\
  ',
```

```js
Vue.component('data-tag', {
  data() {
    return {
      dataend: '',
      days: ''
    }
  },
  template: '<div>\
   <input type="date" placeholder="дата окончания" v-model="dataend">\
   <div> {{days}} days</div>\
   <div class="tab" :class="`tab ${сolorTag}`"></div>\
  </div>\
  ',
  watch: {
    dataend() {
      this.deadline();
    }
  },
  methods: {
    deadline() {
      const msPerDay = 8.64 * Math.pow(10, 7);
      const abs = Date.parse(this.dataend) - Date.now();
      this.days = Math.ceil(abs / msPerDay);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    сolorTag() {
      switch (true) {
        case this.days > 60:
          {
            return 'blue'
          }
        case this.days < 60 && this.days > 14:
          {
            return 'yellow'
          }
        case this.days < 14:
          {
            return 'red'
          }
      }
    }
  }
});
new Vue({
  el: "#data-tag"
})
```

```css
.tab {
  width: 140px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="data-tag">
  <data-tag></data-tag>
</div>
```